# Script that recognizes first sentence, put it inside a heading and the rest inside a paragraph

Tags: php

Hey there, 
I have this code, i take a wordpress post content, put it inside a variable and than match the first sentence, put it inside a h2 heading and the rest inside a paragraph.

1.The problem is this... my script recognizes only . or ! or ? at the end of the first sentance. **Can i make it recognize "..." suspension points?**

2.If in my wordpress post i have a text like this:

The first sentance! followed by some text

**than i hit enter**

continue with more text

My script shows  only "The first sentance! followed by some text" and nothing after the enter that i hit. Why? and ideeas?

Here is the code:

```
ob_start();
the_content();
$old_content = ob_get_clean(); // I put wordpress inside a variable
$content = strip_tags($old_content); // I use strip tags

     preg_match('/(.*?[?.!])(.*)/', $content, $match); 
     $first_sentence = $match[1]; 
     $the_rest = $match[2];

     if ( $first_sentence != '' && $the_rest != '' ):
             echo '<h2>'.$first_sentence.'</h2>';
             echo '<p>'.$the_rest.'</p>';
     else:
     echo '<h2>About me:</h2>';
     endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 preg_match('/(.*?[?\.!]{1,3})(.*)/', $content, $match);
```

Should do it without complicating it too much. It will recognize `...`, `!!!`, `???` that looks ok, but keep in mind that `.!?` will also fit. I'm unfortunately unable to test anything more complicated at the moment.

**Update**

Regarding the second question. It's because regular expression ends at line break. You can turn on multiline mode with `'/(.*?[?\.!]{1,3})(.*)/m'` if I'm not mistaken. But I would suggest changing the code to:

```
 preg_match('/(.*?[?\.!]{1,3})/', $content, $match);
 $first_sentence = $match[1]; 
 $the_rest = substr($content, strlen($first_sentence));
```

as it will have greater performance

Comment: Hey thank you, but what about that part when wordpress serves me content with "enter" spaces, why does the script work only for the content untill it reachers that "enter" space?

Comment: Uh... yeah, it must be because it preg_match takes reference as third argument, so you must define that variable before using it. `$match = null; preg_match...`

Comment: Aster I added this, it takes all my text as firt sentence :( any ideeas?

Comment: Oup, didn't notice at first glance. The dot inside `[]` must be escaped: `/(.*?[?\.!]{1,3})/`

Comment: I have added this to you second solution '/(.*?[?.!]{1,3})(.*)/' and everything works perfect:)

Comment: That is wierd... Allright I'll test it tomorrow when I get to office and see what I'm doing wrong. Can't think of anything @home:).

Comment: That's strange, the sample I wrote in the second part works fine for me. I`m running PHP 5.2.10.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just take everything up to the first newline?

Something like:

```
$firstnewline = strpos($text, "\n");
$header = substr($text, 0, $firstnewline);
$therest = substr($text, $firstnewline + 1);
```

If you want, you can do further processing using strip_tags(), a regexp, or a simple str_replace().